# How can i divide this array to chunks?

Tags: php

I want to divide array into specific chunks

Like

```
array1 = 24%;
     array2 = 50%;
     array3 = 26%;

$myArray = array("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz");
$newArray = array_chunk($myArray, 3, false);
```

Array may contain billions of records.

Comment: The above code is just an example,

Comment: What exactly is your question? You're doing it correctly with `array_chunk`!

Comment: I want to divide array of billions records to chunks with respect to percentage. like first array 25% , second 50% etc.

Comment: And exactly how do you propose to load billions of records into a PHP array? Does your server have a couple terabytes of ram?

Comment: yes we have dedicated servers

Comment: "yes we have dedicated servers" You maybe still better going with some kind of stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Answer (score 4):

```
$cnt=count($myArray);
$cnt1=round($cnt*0.24);
$cnt2=round($cnt*0.5);
```

//use array_slice $here

```
array(
    array_slice($array,0,$cnt1);
    array_slice($array,$cnt1,$cnt2);
    array_slice($array,$cnt1+$cnt2);
);
```